SFMC Track Page View - Item not in catalog error
I'm working with a client on the implementation of Einstein Recommendations and more specifically tracking item/product activity on their website. We've had some issues because, as most of you will know by now, SF's documentation on this topic is not very easy to understand.
Long story short, we have implemented the Streaming Updates API and products are getting recorded in the Catalog in SFMC. However, the Track Page View function does not seem to be working correctly, as we are getting "Viewed Item Not In Catalog" errors.
We made sure that we are sending both ProductCode and SKU via the Streaming Updates API, to prevent any issues with any of those values not getting correctly mapped. After some testing we cleaned out the catalog to ensure we get correct entries, but we are still seeing the "Viewed Item Not In Catalog" message appearing in the Status page in Einstein.
I found out this other question posted and used it as guide: How to match trackingcode to productcatalog?
But even after following all the recommendations, we keep getting the error message and we see 0 items under "Collected Today".

Here's an example of the payload we receive via trackpageview:
{"item":"5246838","title":"Detalle producto | Fischel en línea","url":"https://www.fischelenlinea.com/detalle-producto/AFELIUS-EXPERT-5246838","referrer":""}

And here's a screenshot (apikey obfuscated for security reasons) of the collect.js:

So, any ideas as to why we keep getting the "Viewed Item Not In Catalog" would be greatly appreciated! As a side note, we are not tracking cart activity or capturing any additional user details here, as the user needs to log into the website to purchase, and we first want to track page views for unknown visitors.
Thanks in advance!

are you sure your track item payload is providing the data you expect?

@EazyE Do you know if RedEagle Chrome extension still works? I might have it somewhere, and it might be a good fit for debugging here - I just haven’t used it for ages.

thank you both - well, the only thing I can think of is that we are sending additional values in the payload for trackpageview. Most examples I've seen only carry 'item'. For example: ["trackPageView", { "item": "{CONTENT_ID}" }]

Also, Esteban, I don’t know if you have managed to find this unofficial documentation which IMHO provides most comprehensive technical overview of Collect Code and Recommendations

Why would you want to send anything but the product ID? The rest should come from the catalogue import/updates, and not though trackPageView.

thanks Lukas! I've never seen that document before. And yes, I'm not sure why the developers added those values in the trackPageView payload.

Ok a quick update: we found that the developers were adding two versions of the trackpageview functions: one using a JSON payload (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/pb-collect-tracking.html) and the other using the _etmc.push method. What's the difference between these two? Also, they informed us that the _etmc.push(['trackPageView', { 'item': 'INSERT_PRODUCT_CODE' }]); gets called AFTER page load via a function. Any harm in doing that? Thanks!

Additional update: we are noticing that IGO_VIEWS is not getting populated, while IGO_PRODUCTS is.  "Viewed Item Not In Catalog" errors have significantly decreased, but we are not seeing any actual item page views getting tracked.

We were able to get this working. A critical piece of information that does not seem to be clear is that you MUST create at least a dummy recommendation (Email or Web; there is no difference here) for the system to start recording the visits and match ProductCode with SKU or Item code from the catalog.
